# Excel Lookup In Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I am trying to lookup a value in a table based on the row and column headers (bolded).

For example, I have a table:

[image: Table]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where have you got stuck? What happened when you googled your question? This is a trivial case for using an `INDEX` `MATCH` combination. Google that, and report back here if you need more help after trying what you've found out how to do.

Comment: Better you specify which value you want to extract from the Table,, because any general formula will returns the very first value !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**INDEX & MATCH combination will solve the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Data Range is `A2:D7`.
- Criteria Cells are `G2` & `H2`.
- Formula in `H3`:

`=INDEX($B$3:$D$7,MATCH($H$2,$A$3:$A$7,1),MATCH($G$2,$B$2:$D$2,1))`

- As soon you enter new Row & Column Heading in Criteria cells, you get new answer in `H3`.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Oliver Yasuna ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1):

Try **SUMPRODUCT** function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$1=$B$1:$D$1)*($G$1=$A$2:$A$6),$B$2:$D$6)
```

F1 and G1 enter the Row or Column values, and F2 return result you need.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes your formula returns Zero instead of expected value,, also OP has not specified which Value is expected to returns !!

Comment: emmmm...it seems like the user didn't provide the result he needs, so I give a sample. -.-

Answer (score 1):

A fellow suggested a workaround to a Suggestion on the UserVoice site. It applies here for the general case I think you are trying to ask about. (As opposed to using a results table as above, rather just use it to extract data to some odd spot or into a bigger formula.)

He used the MATCH() function on the column header row to obtain the third argument in VLOOKUP():

```
=VLOOKUP("43",B2:D6,MATCH("71",B1:D1),FALSE)    (returns "41.2")
```

(For "43" one might substitute any form of obtaining the desired lookup value. Simple like this, or a single cell looked to for it like H9 perhaps, or maybe some rather involved formula just to obtain the lookup value. Same idea for the "71", you could obtain the desired column in any number of ways, though of course, the idea here is to use its actual header label.

So if you are looking at cell H9's content for the lookup value and cell J23 for the column to return a value from, it would look like this:

```
=VLOOKUPH9,B2:D6,MATCH(J23,B1:D1),FALSE)
```

which would return the same "41.2" as above if populated with "43" and "71", respectively.

The table can start in any column because the MATCH() is only looking at its column header range, so the fourth column will always be the fourth column even if it begins in column "AM". (You DO need to start the MATCH() range with the first column ("A" in this case), not the second where the labels start in the table you give.

Of course, the same idea would work with HLOOKUP() and row labels.